# How to exclude a directory when syncing a p4 stream

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-stream

I am using the command line tools of Perforce.
And with the p4 tool, I want to sync to a stream.

The problem is that I want to exclude a directory from my workspace.
If my work space was defined as a view, this would be possible with something like:

```
View:
    //depot/Foo/... //Client/Foo/...
    -//depot/Foo...bin/... //Client/Foo...bin/...
```

But the **Stream:** setting overrides the **View:** specification.

I have set the Stream using the command:

```
$ p4 client
```

I also looked into P4IGNORE mechanism, but this is of no use to my problem, as P4IGNORE will not influence the **sync** command.

I tried adding a Paths: command to my client spec, but that is not recognized in this context. I think it is used when specifying the stream, as done by the administrator of the depot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what virtual streams are for.  :) Create a child of the stream with type `virtual`, and exclude the directory from the virtual child stream (via either `Paths` or `Ignore` in the stream spec).  This will generate you a client view that is the desired subset of the parent stream.

https://www.perforce.com/blog/virtual-streams-windows-big-projects